# Hadoop Job : Task fail to report status for 601 seconds

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

While running hadoop job on pseudonode, task fails and got killed.
Error : Task attempt_   fail to report status for 601 seconds

But the same program is running through Eclipse (local job).

Task : there are around 25K  keywords , output will be all possible combination (two  at a time) i.e around 25K * 25K entires

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason the task, when executed on your pseudonode, is not progressing. You can increase the setting "mapred.task.timeout" in mapred-site.xml.
The default value of the same in mapred-default.xml is:

```
 <property>
    <name>mapred.task.timeout</name>
    <value>600000</value>
    <description>The number of milliseconds before a task will be 
                 terminated if it neither reads an input, writes 
                 an output, nor updates its status string.
    </description>
 </property>
```

Answer (score 2):

For testing purposes/one time job or debugging the increment of the time-out value could be a good option, but as practice shows this is not a good solution for the production, you should review and optimize the code.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop Provides the reporting API for the same. If you do not report progress to the hadoop job for 10 mins that is 600 seconds ,it considers task as stucked and kills the task.
API reference is [Here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskInputOutputContext.html#progress%28%29%22Here%22)